# Is it possible to return early in a Redux Action

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, axios

**Issue**
I'm feeling this is a scoping issue. I'm unable to return in the catch block. It's always returning success. While the if statement works for the failure part (i debugged it using console.log).

**Background information**
There is a back-end API which uses laravel. In this piece of code i'm logging in to the API to get a JWT token using react-redux. This token is needed to call the API in the future. The code is working perfectly and is receiving a token on *actual success* but i'm unable to return early on failure.

```
export function requestApiToken(username, password){    
    const url = ROOT_URL + 'user/login';
    const request = axios.post(url, {
        email: username,
        password: password,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
        }
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        //somehow it always returns an error
        //currently 500=succes (will fix that later in api to 200)

        if(error.response.status == 500){
            console.log('succes')
            console.log(error.response.data);
        }else{
            console.log('error')
            console.log(error.response.data);
            return{
                type: FETCH_API_TOKEN_FAILURE,
                token: null,
                message: 'Please enter a valid e-mail and username for the API and try again'
            }
        }
    });

    return{
        type: FETCH_API_TOKEN_SUCCES,
        token: request, //should be error.response.data
        message: 'Succesfull login'
    }
}
```

*Edit As a response to the comment section.*
This is what the server returns:

if block succes(debug)
[image: Succes if block]

if block failure(debug)
[image: Failure if block]

Currently the code always gets in the code block return FETCH_API_TOKEN_SUCCES

### **As suggested in the answers I got it to work by using redux-thunk as my middleware instead of redux-promise**

Added in index.js

```
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
const createStoreWithmiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunk)(createStore);
```

In the requestApiToken method

```
return(dispatch) => {
        request.then(function (response) {
            dispatch({
                type: FETCH_API_TOKEN_SUCCESS,
                token: response.data.token,
                message: 'Successfull login'
            })
        });
        request.catch(function (error) {
            if(error.response.status == 422){
                dispatch({
                        type: FETCH_API_TOKEN_FAILURE,
                        token: null,
                        message: 'Please enter a valid e-mail and username for the DiabetesAPI and try again'
                })
            }
        });

        dispatch({
            type: FETCH_API_TOKEN_PENDING,
            token: null,
            message: 'Pending API Token request'
        });
    }
```

Comment: try to remove your if statement just for debugging prurpose

Comment: @AmrAly i updated my question, i appreciate your help

Comment: I believe you are going to need to use [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) middleware.

Comment: Redux-thunk fixed the problem thanks @AmrAly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of failure, your application flow looks like this:

1. return `FETCH_API_TOKEN_SUCCESS` before `post` promise is resolved
2. network call failed, promise is `rejected` and `catch` block is executed
3. JS engine procced `catch` block statements and returns new promise with `FETCH_API_TOKEN_FAILURE` action type

I suggest you to use three-state approach for network calls, like `PENDING, SUCCESS and FAILURE`. In this case you can show loaders and exactly know when your network call is finished.

```
export function requestApiToken(username, password) {
    const url = ROOT_URL + 'user/login';
    const request = axios.post(url, {
        email: username,
        password: password,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
        }
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        return {
            type: FETCH_API_TOKEN_SUCCESS,
            token: response.token,
            message: 'Successfull login'
        }
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        return {
            type: FETCH_API_TOKEN_FAILURE,
            token: null,
            message: getErrorMessage(error.response.status)
        }
    });

    return Promise.resolve({
        type: FETCH_API_TOKEN_PENDING,
        token: null,
        message: 'Loading'
    });
}

function getErrorMessage(statusCode) {
    if (statusCode == 422) { 
        return 'Please enter a valid e-mail and username for the API and try again';
    } else {
        return 'Error has occurred';
    }
}
```

Note that you need resolve value of action creator by `then` in your reducer, since return value will be `Promise`.

As other guys noticed, you will need [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) middleware for handling promises in reducers.

P.S. You are returning `FETCH_API_TOKEN_SUCCESS` action with `token: request` field. In this case, `request` is a promise and I assume you are properly handle this in further code.

P.S.S Most likely your `catch` block does not return anything because return statement inside catch will be wrapped into promise, and you need to resolve it by `then` or `catch`

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortonately somehow on succes the server returns a 500 error. I added this to my original question. It's not getting in the .then block but it's always in the catch block(just the error status depends). Also the token failure part is not distpached in your answer is not dispatching somehow. Any idea?

Comment: you mean 500 error in my approach or original one? 500 error will not be dispatched, because catch block only returns some value when status code is 422, it is not good approach as well. You should return some action anyway, but maybe specify the error message. I can update my answer if needed

Comment: On succes the server is responding with 500. On failure it's responding with 422. Somehow the .then is never executed at all tried at console.log

Comment: Because 500 is not a successful status, it should be processed in catch block

Comment: then will be executed only if status code is between 200 and 299

Comment: I will edit the API to return 200 in the future but for now i was trying it in the catch block and update it to .then in the future

Comment: you can manually return `SUCCESS` action in catch block, like `if (error.response.status == 500) { return { type: FETCH_API_TOKEN_SUCCESS } else { return { type: FETCH_API_TOKEN_FAILURE }}`, but please, use it only for debugging purposes. It should work since any return from catch will be thenable Promise

Comment: Please use HTTP Status Codes as they are designed

Comment: Redux-thunk was the solution, i added the pending state. and fixed the result  codes to be 200 OK. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Jouke sounds great! Glad you figured it out

Answer (score 1):

Uh, there's a lot of issues with your code. Might be a good idea to take things slowly and learn how each of the concepts you are trying to use work.

Action creator is a function that returns a plain object describing an action.

Axios is a library that lets you make requests to your server. Axios.post() will return a promise, which lets you handle results of the request using then() and catch() methods. These methods take callback functions, and you've properly supplied your catch() call with one. The problem is that the return statement in your callback returns from callback, not from the action creator. You can't make an asynchronous API call in an action creator then return an action from a success or failure callback.

Another problem is that you are returning success action just after your Axios.post() call. This means that action creator will return a success action as soon as it makes the call, without waiting for it to return a response.

If you want to make API calls in your action creators, take a look at [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) which is Redux middleware that lets you return promises from action creators which can in turn dispatch their own actions when resolved or rejected.

Comment: Redux thunk fixed the answer, thanks for your feedback